# Pronunciation of “tous” — Prononciation de « tous »

Tags: grammaire, prononciation

I'm very confused about it. *Tous* is pronounced sometimes “*tou*” sometimes “*tousse*”. Is there a fairly simple rule for that?

I found [this document](http://www.atala.org/doc/actes_taln/AC_0009.pdf) but I really couldn't understand it and I think it is over-complicated.

---

Je suis perdu. *Tous* est des fois prononcé « *tou* » et parfois « *tousse* ». Est-ce qu'il existe une règle simple pour connaître la bonne prononciation ?

J'ai trouvé [ce document](http://www.atala.org/doc/actes_taln/AC_0009.pdf), mais je ne comprends pas vraiment ce qu'il dit et il me semble qu'il ne fait que compliquer les choses.

Comment: _French_ is over-complicated

Comment: Your linked document is an academic paper, that is to say the exact opposite of a tutorial.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When *tous* is a **pronoun** you pronounce the **s** :

- Ils sont tous */tus/* là.
- À boire pour tous */tus/* !

When it is an **adjective** you don't pronounce the **s** :

- Je me lève à six heures tous */tu/* les jours.
- « Il m'a demandé une liste de tous */tu/* les participants.
  — Tous */tu/* les participants ?
  — Oui, tous */tus/*. »

---

Le **s** se prononce quand *tous* est employé comme pronom et ne se prononce pas quand il est employé comme adjectif.