# Prononciation de « in » et « im »

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, nasalisation

Est-ce qu'il y a une règle pour savoir s'il faut prononcer `/ɛ̃/` ou `/in/` ?

J'ai l'impression que si le *n* est suivi d'une voyelle, c'est `/in/`, est-ce que c'est aussi simple que ça ?

Comment: Si après 7 heures personne n'a trouvé un contre-exemple, ça doit vouloir dire que c'est en effet aussi simple que ça ! Pour ma part les seuls cas tangents que je note sont « inhabité », « inhalé » etc… qui sont suivis d'un son voyelle mais pas d'une voyelle à proprement parler… Par ailleurs, est-ce que la règle ne s'étendrait pas aussi aux groupes de lettres *an*, *am*, (*en*, *em*), *on*, *om*, et *un*, *um* ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Après presque 10 mois, mais les contre-exemples [existent bien](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/4478/1514) :·)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il y a malheureusement quelques exceptions.

Pour les mots comme *immédiat* ou *immatériel*, le second `m` ne "compte pas" pour la règle. De même pour *innovation* et *innocent* par exemple. Un `h` après `in-` ne compte pas non-plus (et est généralement (toujours?) suivi d'une voyelle).

Mais pour *immangeable*, *immettable* et *immanquable*, on prononce généralement avec le même son que *imbuvable*  ou *impressionnant*, en tous cas en France métropolitaine. [Cet article](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/prefix-in/) liste aussi *immariable* avec cette prononciation.

Faire une exception simplement pour les mots commençant par `imm-` et finissant par `-able` ne fonctionne pas: le premier son de *immuable* est bien semblable à celui de *imitable*.

Comment: On dirait qu'il s'agit de tous les mots récents construits à partir de im (négatif) + dérivé d'un verbe avec le suffixe -able. L'exception de l'exception est effectivement immuable, qui est bcp plus ancien et dans le cas duquel "muer" n'est presque plus utilisé dans le sens de générique changer (il s'est spécialisé en changer de voix, de peau ou de plume)

Answer (score 5):

Here's another (perhaps more explanatory) way of looking at it: imagine a set of ordered rules which convert letters to sounds step by step. I won't try to set them all out but first apply a rule that reduces a written geminate consonant (the same consonant repeated as in *immédiat*) to a single phonological consonant. Then transform letters to sounds on a straight one to one basis (OK I'm brushing over lots of complications) Now, if a vowel and following nasal consonant are in the same phonological syllable, nasalisation occurs, as in im-po-ssible: If on the other hand there is a syllable boundary separating the vowel and nasal, then nasalisation is blocked and the two sounds remain separate, as in i-ma-gi-ner. (Remember French and other romance languages prefer open syllables i.e ones ending in a vowel). This will account for all the pairs like artisan - artisane if we apply the rule that deletes the schwa *after* nasalisation.

Comment: Thanks. Having looked up geminate, phonological and schwa, I *think* I understand...

Answer (score 5):

La règle générale est que `mm` et `nn` sont prononcés [m]/[n]. Elles n'entraînent la nasalisation de la voyelle précédente que lorsque le M/N est suivi d'une consonne différente ou se trouve en fin de mot.

Quand un mot est formé avec le préfix `in-` et un radical commençant par M ou N, la prononciation du mot commence donc par [im]/[in]. Il y a des fois un doublement ([gémination](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9mination)) de la consonne (ceci vaut aussi lorsque `in-` + `r…` forme `irr…` ou `in-` + `l…` forme `ill…`). La gémination n'est pas phonémique en français : le doublement ou non de la consonne n'a pas d'impact sémantique, il est au gré de la personne qui parle et peut dépendre de l'individu, de la place dans la phrase, de l'accentuation, etc. La gémination est plus courante dans les mots où le préfixe est apparu en français, par opposition à ceux ou le mot avec le préfixe est hérité du latin. Elle est rare dans les mots où la forme sans le préfixe a disparu (par exemple *innocent*).

Il y a quelques exceptions, seulement avec le préfixe *in-* qui indique une négation (pas d'exception lorsque *in-* indique l'intérieur), et même dans certains de ces cas les deux prononciations existent. Pour `imm-`, le [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/immacul%C3%A9) cite *immangeable*, *immanquable*, *immaniable*, *immariable*, *immettable*. Je ne trouve pas de liste pour `in-` ; le TLF cite par exemple les deux prononciations pour  [*innavigable*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/innavigable). De même, `in-` + `r…` devient `irr…` et `in-` + `l…` devient `ill…` à très peu d'exceptions près : (*[inlassable](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inlassable)*, *[inracontable](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inracontable)*.

Ces exceptions ont en commun que ce sont des formations récentes, datant d'après l'apparition des voyelles nasales en français ; mais je ne crois pas que toutes les formations récentes aient échappé à la nasalisation. Je ne sais pas si le fait que toutes les exceptions ont le suffixe *-able* est une coïncidence (c'est un suffixe courant parmi les adjectifs dont on a tendance à utiliser la négation).

---

The general rule is that double M and double N are pronounced [m]/[n]. Nasalization of the preceding vowel only occurs when the M/N is followed by a different consonant or at the end of the word.

When the prefix `in-` is added to a word beginning with M or N, the pronunciation therefore starts with [im]/[in]. There is sometimes doubling ([gemination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination)) of the consonant (this also happens when `in-` + `r…` becomes `irr…` or `in-` + `l…` becomes `ill…`). Gemination in French isn't phonemic, i.e. a pronunciation of [im] vs. [imm] doesn't carry a meaningful distinction and can be up to the individual speaker, the place of the word in the sentence, the stress, ... It is more common in words where the prefix was added in French, as opposed to words with the prefix that date back to Latin. It is rare in words where the form without the prefix doesn't exist in French (e.g. *innocent*).

There are just a few exceptions, only with the prefix *in-* that indicates a negation (no exceptions when *in-* indicates “inside”), and even in some of those cases both pronunciations exist. For `imm-`, the [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/immacul%C3%A9) cites *immangeable*, *immanquable*, *immaniable*, *immariable*, *immettable*. I can't find a list for `inn-`; the TLF cites both pronunciations for [*innavigable*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/innavigable), for example. Similarly `in-` + `l…` becomes `ill-` and `in-` + `r…` becomes `irr`, with very few exceptions (*[inlassable](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inlassable)*, *[inracontable](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/inracontable)*).

What the exceptions have in common is that they're recent formations, all dating from after nasalization appeared in French; but I don't think all recent formations undergo nasalization. I don't know if the fact that all of these examples end with the suffix *-able* is a coincidence (it is a common suffix for adjectives that tend to get negated).

Comment: En ce qui concerne les doubles n, en Occitanie on les nasalise, par exemple "année" est souvent prononcé "an né"

Answer (score 1):

En plus des cas, comme relève [Mat](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2049/1514), où le doublement de la consonne vient invalider la règle, ***ou pas***, ça n'est [jamais](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/pronunciation-of-tous?rq=1#comment3270_1800) aussi simple que ça :

- *Intifada*, *input*, *incipit* pour piocher dans les non-gallicismes ;
- [*Inria*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inria) et l'[*Inra*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institut_national_de_la_recherche_agronomique), pour les acronymes ;
- *Ingrid* dans les prénoms.

Mais sinon, oui, la règle tient mieux la route que bien d'autres (^_^)