# La prononciation de « in » en début de mot

Tags: prononciation, préfixes, nasalisation

En général on prononce la combinaison des lettres « in » avec la voyelle nasale /ɛ̃/ (par exemple *inconnu*). Cependant, j'ai remarqué qu'on la prononce parfois comme /in/ (par example *inacceptable*).
J'ai commencé à croire que le préfixe latin de négation *in-* est toujours prononcé comme /in/, mais il y a beaucoup d'exceptions, par exemple *inconnu*, *incroyable*, *insatisfait* etc.

Alors je me demande s'il y a un moyen de savoir quand on doit dire /ɛ̃/ et quand on doit dire /in/ ?

---

Generally, you pronounce the letter combination "in" with the nasal vowel /ɛ̃/ (e.g. *inconnu*). However, I have noticed that it is sometimes pronounced like /in/ (e.g. *inacceptable*). I started to think that the Latin negative prefix *in-* always is pronounced like /in/, but there are quite a few exceptions, e.g. *inconnu*, *incroyable*, *insatisfait* etc.

So, is there any way to know when you pronounced it like /ɛ̃/ and when you pronounce it like /in/?

Comment: Voir aussi [Prononciation de 'in' et 'im'](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/prononciation-de-in-et-im), surtout pour `im-` (qui a quelques exceptions, contrairement à `in-`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C'est selon,

- `/ɛ̃/` lorsque ***in-*** est suivi d'une consonne autre que **h** ou **n** ;
- `/in/` lorsqu'il est suivi d'une voyelle ou de **h** ou que le **n** est doublé.

Cette règle s'applique plus généralement lorsqu'une voyelle est suivie de **m** ou **n**, pour décider si la consonne change le son de la voyelle en un son nasal ou si la consonne est prononcée.

Answer (score 3):

Dans le tableau que l'on trouve [ici](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais#cite_note-mn-12), on peut voir que si "***i***" (de même que a,b,c,d,e,f,j,k)  est suivi de *m*, *n*, *h* ou d'une *voyelle*, alors le **n** ou le **m** se prononcent au lieu de changer le son de la voyelle précédente.