# Prononciation de « immangeable »

Tags: prononciation, préfixes, nasalisation

Je voudrais comprendre pourquoi est-ce qu'on prononce le mot *immangeable* comme [ɛ̃mɑ̃ʒabl]. Je pensais qu'il fallait dire [imɑ̃ʒabl] parce qu'on prononce des mots comme *immense*, *immobile*, *immature*, etc. avec [im-] et non [ɛ̃m-]. Est-ce qu'il s'agit simplement d'une exception ?

Comment: Il y en a d'autres comme ça: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/prononciation-de-in-et-im

Comment: … sans parler de enamouré (comme : en amouré, avec liaison), ininflammable etc.. Sometimes I'd like to be an English-speaking person (except that enough may come from German genug, but the pronunciation has … evolved)

Comment: Je ne pense pas être le seul à prononcer parfois [imɑ̃ʒabl], parfois [ɛ̃mɑ̃ʒabl]. En revanche, je ne dis bien que [ɛ̃mɑ̃kabl] et [ɛ̃metabl].

Comment: et de toute façon, la tendance est à le "prononcer" *pas mangeable*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je pense que les mots comme *immangeable*, *immettable* et les autres exception sont des mots qui sont apparus bien plus tard.

*Immobile* et *immatériel* viennent directement du latin tels quels (on a pas rajouté de préfixe aux mots latins), alors que *immangeable*, *immettable* et autres sont bien plus [récents](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=immangeable%2Cimmettable&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmangeable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimmettable%3B%2Cc0). (Voir aussi [*immanquable*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=immanquable&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmanquable%3B%2Cc0))

Ces derniers ont été créés sur la base de tous les autres "*in- + [verbe] + -able*", et dans ces cas-là le préfixe se prononce toujours [ɛ̃].

D'ailleurs j'ai l'impression qu'on a ce phénomène uniquement avec les mots en *-able*, en attestent des mots comme [*immoral* et *immature*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=immature%2C+immoral&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmature%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimmoral%3B%2Cc0), qui pourtant ne viennent pas directement du latin.

Answer (score 2):

Il existe une règle qui interdit d'employer la lettre *n* avant la lettre *m* ou la lettre *p*. Dans ce cas on remplace la lettre *n* par la lettre *m* à l'écrit mais on garde la prononciation comme s'il y avait encore la lettre *n*.

Par exemple on écrit *impossible*, bien que cela signifie *in* + *possible*, et cela se prononce comme *in* + *possible*.

Ce n'est pas spécifique au préfixe *in*. Par exemple on écrit *emménager* mais cela se prononce comme *en* + *ménager*, on écrit *empire* mais on le prononce comme *en* + *pire*, etc.

Les mots [immense](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/immense), [immobile](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/immobile) et [immature](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/immature) ont été empruntés au latin et leur prononciation et dérivée du latin. Je dirais que ce sont eux les exceptions. (pour info [immangeable](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/immangeable) n'est **pas** dérivé du latin)

Comment: Cela ne répond pas à la question, qui est, de façon simplifiée « pourquoi, puisque « in mobile » est prononcé « i mobile » n'est-ce pas le cas aussi pour « in mangeable » ? ». La transformation du n en m n'a pas d'incidence puisque elle se retrouve dans les deux cas. Faut-il conclure que les cas comme « immobile » sont des exceptions ?