# Prononciation de « toutes » — Pronunciation of “toutes”

Tags: prononciation, pronoms

C’est clair qu’[il faut prononcer le “s” quand “tous” est employé comme pronom](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/pronunciation-of-tous-prononciation-de-tous). J’aimerais savoir si ceci est aussi le cas pour le pronom “toutes”.

Par exemple:

- Bonjour à toutes !
- Les chambres ? Elle les a toutes nettoyées.

---

Clearly [the *s* in *tous*, used as a pronoun, is voiced](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/pronunciation-of-tous-prononciation-de-tous). I would like to know whether the *s* in *toutes*, the feminine variant of the pronoun, is voiced as well.

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/toutes est ce que tu cherches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Toutes*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/toutes) même en tant que pronom se prononce toujours `[tutə]`, le *s* n'est pas prononcé.

Que dire de plus ?

Comment: Le *s* n'est jamais prononcé non plus dans *plûtes*. Mais c'est vrai qu'il n'est jamais prononcé dans *plus* lorsque c'est un verbe, de toute façon.