# Pronunciation of "tous" in "tous ceux"

Tags: pronoms, prononciation, adjectifs

> Je voudrais remercier tous ceux qui ont aidé avec l'organisation de l'événement.

How is *tous* pronounced here? I know that the pronunciation [depends](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/pronunciation-of-tous-prononciation-de-tous) on whether *tous* is a pronoun or an adjective, but I'm not sure what it is here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, ***tous*** is an adjective agreeing with the pronoun ***ceux*** so according to the rule you linked to is pronounced **/tu/**.

Had it been pronounced **/tus/**, that would have lead to **/tus.sø/**.

Compare:

> *Je veux les miens **plus ceux** de mon frère* (I want mine and those of my brother)

where *plus ceux* is pronounced **/plys.sø/** and:

> *Je ne vois **plus ceux** de mon frère* (I don't see those of my brother anymore)

where *plus ceux* is pronounced **/ply.sø/**.

Answer (score 2):

It's always pronounced /tusø/.

*Tous* is a determiner here (hence feminine form *toutes celles* /tut sɛl/), but the /s/ is combined to the one at the beginning of *ceux*, so it would be pronounced the exact same way whether *tous* were /tus/ or just /tu/.

The only case I can think of where the pronunciation may be different is in Quebec, for speakers who have only the invariable form /tut/ regardless of what standard grammar would have. In that case, you would have /tut sø/ instead (spelled *toutes ceux*, but *toutes ceusse* is more likely when you get to that degree of [joual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joual)), but this is considered nonstandard even for Quebec French.

Comment: I'm from Quebec, and I would personally go with either /tusø/ or /tut sø/ (incorrect, yes), which are both common. /søz/ is a heard a lot less, though it does indeed exist. When a was a teenager, we used to make fun at this through an informal feminine of 2 _(une plus une égal **deuze**)._