# Why is “tous les mains” used here instead of “toutes les mains”?

Tags: pronoms

Below is the quote from *Candide*:

> Candide et Martin aperçurent distinctement une centaine d'hommes sur le tillac du vaisseau qui s'enfonçait ; ils levaient **tous les mains** au ciel et jetaient des clameurs effroyables ; en un moment tout fut englouti.

"Les mains" is feminine plural, why not "toutes les mains"?
I am a newbie in French, please explain it to me in English, many thanks!

Comment: You could rephrase it like this: *"Tous levaient les mains au ciel"*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Tous les mains" is indeed invalid as a unit (since "mains" is feminine), but it is nonetheless a valid sequence of words in this sentence because it is not being used as a unit. "Tous" is an pronoun, not an adjective here. It is not connected to the following noun phrase; rather, it refers back to the subject "ils" (with which it agrees).

This may become more apparent if you try to translate the text to English: "They raised *all their hands* to heaven" doesn't make as much sense as "*They all* raised their hands to heaven.../*All of them* raised their hands to heaven..."

Note that [the pronoun "tous" is pronounced /tus/](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1800), with the consonant sound /s/ at the end, unlike the adjective "tous" which is /tu/ before consonants and /tu.z/ before vowels.

Here is a thread on the Wordreference forums that you may find helpful: [FR: tout / toute / tous / toutes](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-tout-toute-tous-toutes.458453/)

Comment: And to add a generalizing element, the asker can expect to see this subject + verb + *tous* quite often. « Est-ce que vous avez tous vos feuilles de papier ? Bon, on peut commencer ... »

Comment: WRONG big time. see RRMX (i'm french...), the correct translation is "they all raised their hands"

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier: Which part of this answer should I change? Are you saying it is overly literal to include "to heaven" in the English translation?

Answer (score 2):

*tous* here applies to *ils*, not *les mains*. Therefore, it is perfectly valid.

In English you would phrase it as *They were all raising their hands*

You can trust Voltaire with his French, it was top notch!